# How do I implement proper Exception handling in Java?

Tags: java

I am currently writing a simple program in Java in response to a question. The question says :

> You are fixing a bug where documents (represented as a String) are failing to be converted to proper xml. This problem can occur because either:
>   A. Certain characters fail in the xml, or
>   B. Documents passed in have a length > 100 characters (they’re small documents)

It then lists 5 characters that need escaping (e.g. replace '">'" with the escape sequence;).

I've coded the part to replace special characters with escapes, but I'm not sure what to do about the length.

```
if (length of string > 100) {
    do what?
}
```

I was thinking of maybe implementing a try catch statement, but that's used for runtime exceptions correct? (null pointer, etc). In a design standpoint, what would be the best way to avoid this bug while at the same time completing the job of the function?

Comment: Maybe you are thinking of throwing the exception, not catching it --> `throw`

Comment: `try-catch` is used exactly for exceptions that are *not* of the `RuntimeException` type.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Categorically not true.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis what is used for exceptions that are not `RuntimeException` is the `throws` clause in method declaration.

Answer (score 3):

You are not handling an exception here, rather you should probably throw one:

```
private static final int MAX_LENGTH = 100;
// ...

if (inputString.length() > MAX_LENGTH) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException(
      String.format("String is too large. Found %d characters, maximum is %d.",
          inputString.length(), MAX_LENGTH));
}
```

This is the typical way you notify a user of your method that they've violated the API. Make sure your method documentation specifies that the String cannot be greater than 100 characters.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, I forgot about throwing exceptions. Thanks.

Comment: FWIW that exception message would be *much* more useful if it included the observed length of the string, and the limit.  E.g. `"String is too large (found 532 characters, maximum allowed is 100 characters)"`.  Speaking from experience, an error message that just says "no" is less helpful(/more infuriating) than one that tells you *why*.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle Very true. I omitted that level of detail for brevity, but you are completely correct. I've edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions should occur when something *exceptional* occurs.  You should never code using an exception to control your business logic (especially if it's a third party exception like a NoEntityFound, what if the rules around the third party exception being thrown change?).

If the length is genuinely something you need to halt for and tell the user about, throw a custom exception such as...

```
throw new IllegalStringLength("String length invalid");
```

However, if this is something you can do without throwing an exception and handle more gracefully, I'd generally say it's better to do so.  It's not like a null pointer or a database couldn't connect.

You'd then have to catch the above exception and output it to the user (again, using the exception to control your application flow).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, your function converts Strings of a length of < 100 to XML. So from a design-perspective I see no problem in throwing a IllegalArgumentException when the given Strings length is >= 100.

You should not try to continue execution, there is a reason why Exceptions stop the execution of the function - to guarantee correct results that fit the contract of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own Exception class :

```
public class FileTooLongForXmlException extends Exception{
    public FileTooLongForXmlException() {
        super("Your file is > 100 carac");
    }
}
```

And then you just do :

```
if (length of string > 100) {
    throw new FileTooLongForXmlException();
}
```

Comment: ... maybe. I'd always try and use an existing exception if possible (like `IllegalArgumentException`).

Comment: Well, i think it depends, if it's library-oriented it might be usefull to create your own Exceptions, but i agree both answers are okay